# How add attribute to Admin Product's custom tab

Tags: magento, tabs, product, custom-attributes

i have created a tab on admin product. by following way.

```
  <adminhtml_catalog_product_edit>
    <reference name="product_tabs">
        <action method="addTab" ifconfig="customoptionspricing/general/enable" ifvalue="1">
            <name>customoptionspricing_tab</name>
            <block>customoptionspricing/adminhtml_catalog_product_tab</block>
        </action>
    </reference>
</adminhtml_catalog_product_edit>
```

Tab shows perfectly, i have some custom data to show in its phtml file.

Now i have to show product custom attribute in this tab's contents. i do not know how can i add this by using this phtml file, or any other way.

i tried to add attribute like this:

```
    $setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
    $setup->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'is_cop_product', array(
                 'group'    => 'Custom Options Pricing',
                 'label'    => 'Is Custom Options Pricing (COP) Product',            
                 'type' => 'int',
                 'input'    => 'boolean',                     
                 'visible'  => true,
                 'required' => true,
                 'position' => 1,
                 'global'   => 'Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL',
         'note'    => "is product a cop product"
    ));
```

but this way it creates another tab(new Group), with this attribute.

So i need this attribute to be added on tab that i already created.?? thanks

Comment: Did you find some more info about this? I only use the `addAttribute` to add a custom attribute. But I used the `general` group. Now I'm figuring out how to change the group for the custom attribute so it shows up in another tab.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `used_in_forms`.

```
Mage::getSingleton( 'eav/config' )
    ->getAttribute( 'catalog_product','is_cop_product')
    ->setData( 'used_in_forms', array( 'customoptionspricing_tab' ) )
    ->save();
```

This has worked for us on 1.8 and 1.9 . In our case it was a customer attribute but I don't see why it wouldn't work for products.